# Magento Venia PWA wrong PDP pages

Tags: error, pwa-studio, venia, pdp

MAGENTO_BACKEND_URL=https://pwa02.wsl/ (M2 here working well, all pages exists)
DEV_SERVER_HOST=pwa02.dev.wsl
DEV_SERVER_PORT=10000

Ubuntu 20.04 over WSL2
Apache 2
PHP 7.4
MySQL 8.0
Magento 2.4.3
Venia sample data installed

Installation:

1. git clone https://github.com/magento/pwa-studio.git
2. sudo yarn install
3. MAGENTO_BACKEND_URL=https://pwa02.wsl/   yarn buildpack create-env-file packages/venia-concept
4. sudo yarn buildpack create-custom-origin packages/venia-concept
5. sudo yarn run build
6. sudo yarn run watch:venia (watch console output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CxfFW.jpg)

Home, category, account working well, pdps on https://pwa02.wsl/ working well too but "Looks like the page you were hoping to find doesn't exist" on http://pwa02.dev.wsl:10000/chloe-silk-shell and others

[image]